# How to use same ajax event across two datatables included in a single page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I got a .xhtml document including two datatables. Each datatable has several ajax events attached to it. The first datatable has a column with link within. If you click on one of them, it opens the second datatable and you can come back to the first one thanks to a button.

The structure looks like this :

Main page :

```
<html>
   <h:body>

      // Stuff ...

    <div>
        // Including first datatable
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{GenericReportControllerBean.reportType == 'object'}">
            <ui:include src="/site/dialog/uiDatatableGenericReport.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="uiGenericBean" value="#{GenericReportControllerBean}"></ui:param>
                <ui:param name="rowStyleClass" value=""></ui:param>
            </ui:include>
        </ui:fragment>

      // Including second datatable
      <ui:fragment rendered="#{GenericReportControllerBean.reportType == 'family'}" >
          <ui:include src="/site/dialog/uiDatatableFamilyReport.xhtml">
              <ui:param name="uiGenericBean" value="#{GenericReportControllerBean}"></ui:param>
              <ui:param name="rowStyleClass" value="#{object[3] &lt; 0 ? &apos;red&apos; : &apos;&apos;} #{object[3] &gt; 0 ? &apos;orange&apos; : &apos;&apos;}"></ui:param>
              <ui:param name="subid" value="family"></ui:param>
            </ui:include>
        </ui:fragment>

   </div>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Datatables have same structure. Headers are the same (which is probably an error cause they share same rows and same ids)

```
<p:dataTable id="objects#{((subid==null)?'':subid)}" 
        rows="#{uiGenericBean.rows}" lazy="true"
        // others attributes

        // Some code...

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="objects#{((subid==null)?'':subid)}" />
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="objects#{((subid==null)?'':subid)}" />
        <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="objects#{((subid==null)?'':subid)}" />
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="objects#{((subid==null)?'':subid)}" />
        <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="updateFilters()" />
        <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{uiGenericBean.selectAllObjects}" update="objects#{((subid==null)?'':subid)}" />
    </p:dataTable>
```

My problem is the following : evertyhing is working well until I go into the second datatable. After this, if I go back to the first table and select a row, all rows become selected.

If I remove the ajax events from any datatable, this behaviour stops but my submit button is enabled only if a row is selected. Then without the ajax event and update, my button is never enabled.

I also noticed that, if I remove the update attribute from any table but let the ajax event, the problem persists.

I tried to change the id of both tables but it still does not solve the problem.

I also thought about putting the ajax events in the main page instead, but these tables are used in others pages in the programm.

Any idea why I have this behaviour and how to avoid it ?

Comment: Maybe the selectableDataModel is not implemented correctly. Hard to guess without [mcve].

Comment: and maybe there are other things wrong. Making it even harder to gues.. So @Selaron is right... Always, always, always try to create a [mcve],  no template, no includes, no database things etc... You create that for your self first but it is also useful when creating a question here.

Comment: It's a good advice. I will try to make a minimal reproductible and post it if i'm still stucked. Thanks.